# Upload to a central (not user's private) Dropbox account

Tags: android, ftp, sftp, dropbox-api

I'd like to upload files created by app users to a single pre-specified Dropbox account. Basically, this is like using Dropbox as ftp server with single login, but hopefully more secure. How can this be done?  All the Dropbox tutorials show how to link to user's private account, which is not what is needed.

A non-Dropbox solution which does not require much coding would also be welcome. For example, an alternative could be to use SFTP, but there seems to be no standard stable SFTP library for Android.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this securely with Dropbox. You would have to put your account's access token in the Android app, and anyone who got ahold of it could delete all the files there, upload their private DVD collection, etc. It's not safe (or allowed) to share your Dropbox credentials with others.

Comment: I agree about the security issues the users can cause, its a relevant note. However, this is not a general audience "production" app, the users can be trusted. My concern is protecting the users from the outside world. Ftp is insecure since it sends login credentials unencrypted, so anyone listening to the channel could get the data. Dropbox does much safer authentication.