# iOS Dropbox SDK linked to central account

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using the iOS Dropbox SDK for the first time.

I am attempting to link my app to a central/master Dropbox account that I can save files to. This is so my client can view PDF files that are created and submitted from the app.

The documentation for the Dropbox SDK is very centric to connect the app with the user's own Dropbox account and not a central account. There doesn't appear to be anything on how to accomplish what I desire. Is there a simple way to do this?

I think I will be able to do this using the Core API and OAuth, but it would be much simpler if the SDK can handle this and I have just overlooked something.

Comment: This is possible but very much not recommended. You can find a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27834922/auto-login-dropbox-account-on-core-api-without-login-prompt/27845255

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Dropbox SDK is give your app sync functionality between all user's devices, but you are trying to misuse it. You may use sharing between user's accounts but not one Dropbox account as central account unless you provide app with you own credentials and somehow hack the security system.

In your case it would be better to use something like AWS, Parse or analogues

Comment: Unfortunately client has a fairly strict requirement to save these files to a nominated Dropbox account. Will keep searching for a valid workaround

Comment: @Tys well, but look for example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772930/upload-to-a-central-not-users-private-dropbox-account, the question age is almost a year but owner haven't found a solution yet